# If statement checked only once?

Tags: android, if-statement, sdk

I have an issue with a simple if statement. I want to modify the visibility of 2 ImageView with the help of incoming data. For some reason, the data only affects the if statement once. Where is the statement suppose to be so that it continuously refresh?

This is inside my onCreate()

```
        if (TCPClient.Led.equals(High)){
            Inum1.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);
            Inum2.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
        }
        if (TCPClient.Led.equals(Low)){
            Inum1.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
            Inum2.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);
        }
```

I get the data from another class:

```
                while (mRun) {
                serverMessage = in.readLine();

                if (serverMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                    //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                    mMessageListener.messageReceived(serverMessage);
                    Log.e("Listenner",serverMessage);
                    TCPClient.Led = new String(serverMessage);
                }
                serverMessage = null;

            }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Its complicated to determine just with this amount of code, the second chunk of code is an activity returning to a previous activity or creating a new one? If it's the first case, you should put it on the onRestart() method, 'cause it wont pass again by the onCreate(). If it doesn't work, please put more info.

Comment: I didn't put all of my code since it's really long and only this part is important for my issue (I believe). The first code is in my Activity "domotique" and my second chunk of code is in a "TCPClient" class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's done in your onCreate, it's only done once, when your activity is created. You should put your if statement in your loop to check everytime you get a new message.

Comment: Which loop should I put it in? In my messageReceived()

Comment: Well everytime your TCPClient.Led value is changed, you can call a function to update your views. If your activity is in a different thread, there are many ways to do that. I like to implement a communication interface in the activity so the tcp thread can call this interface and update the UI.